# MFMessageComposeViewController presented without recipient field (iOS 11)

Tags: ios11, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller, messageui

When I present MFMessageComposeViewController on an iOS 11 device it's presented mysteriously missing the recipient field. The same code works on an iPhone 6 running iOS 10.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of messing around, I found that if I remove my project-wide hiding of the status bar in my **info.plist**: **View controller-based status bar appearance: NO**
and instead manually prefer that the status bar is hidden in each of my own view controllers I got the correct behavior. This seems like a bug to me so I plan on filing a radar.

You need to set the below in each of your `UIViewController` subclasses if you want to retain the status bar behavior:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```